# how transferring data to connected bluetooth LE device

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, hex, bluetooth-lowenergy

I connected to a bluetooth LE device with below instructions and samples:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt.html#getService(java.util.UUID)

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothLeGatt

but i have no idea how i can send data (hexa code) to ble device,
can anyone help me?
does below code send data to device :

```
BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic.getDescriptor(
UUID.fromString(SampleGattAttributes.CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG));
int hexaCode =Integer.parseInt("7c",16);
descriptor.setValue( 
ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(hexaCode).array());
mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
```

Answer (score 2):

BLE receive data only on services. Services can be custom or BLE standers.ON device connect discover all Ble services and find-out all available service(with there UUIDs and capabilities) on that device.You can download nordic semiconductors **nRF connect application** for better understanding of BLE read and write